# How to setup dinghy for docker on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dinghy

I have setup docker, docker-machine, docker-engine, brew on ubuntu 16.04 system successfully.

I am trying to setup dinghy using below command.

```
$ brew tap codekitchen/dinghy
$ brew install dinghy
```

But not able to setup dinghy.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew is for Macos and not for Ubuntu. Also I guess dinghy is not supported in Ubuntu. It is only for Mac Os

Comment: Actually homebrew is not just for OS X. There's also a Linux version. https://github.com/Linuxbrew.